# unable to send json as guzzle post body

Tags: php, json, guzzle, guzzle6

**Solved**
This is for use with the ecomdash api as it turns out when using this method all json strings must be enclosed in square brackets as if there was an array of products. So this actually works as expected with json_encode for an array of products but with only one product being updated you have to manually add the square brackets around the json. So because of this you have to use body not json when setting up the request. so here is the final code that worked.

```
$data[] = array("Sku" => "067567", "Quantity" => 21, "WarehouseId" => 28345);
    $dataJson = json_encode($data);

    //put square brackets in if only one product is being updated
    if(count($data) == 1) {
      $dataJson = '['.$dataJson.']';
    }

    $headers = $this->auth;
    $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $params = array('headers' => $headers,
                    'json' => $data);

    $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'inventory/updateQuantityOnHand', array('headers' => $headers, 'body' => $dataJson));

    var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
    die();
  }
```

I have searched everywhere and tried a million things but I keep getting the same error when trying to send json as a POST request with guzzle.

The headers I am sending are just credentials for the api I am using and they are working with other requests so I don;'t think they are the issue.

here is some of the code I have used.

```
$data = array("Sku" => "067567", "Quantity" => 10, "WarehouseId" => 
  28345);
$dataJson = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$headers = $this->auth;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
$params = array('headers' => $headers,
                'body' => $dataJson);

$response = $this->client-
   >post('inventory/updateQuantityOnHand',$params);



$data = array("Sku" => "067567", "Quantity" => 10, "WarehouseId" => 
  28345);
$headers = $this->auth;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
$params = array('headers' => $headers,
                'json' => $data);

$response = $this->client-
  >post('inventory/updateQuantityOnHand',$params);
```

the error I am getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://ecomdash.azure-api.net/api/inventory/updateQuantityOnHand` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"Message":"The body of your request was missing or invalid","ExceptionMessage":"The body of your request was missing or invalid","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null} (truncated...) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sunglasses/libraries/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sunglasses/libraries/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sunglasses/libraries/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sunglasses/libraries/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promis in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sunglasses/libraries/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 111

**info from the debug flag**

```
> POST /api/inventory/updateQuantityOnHand HTTP/1.1
Host: ecomdash.azure-api.net
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.1.8
Content-Type: application/json
ecd-subscription-key: *****************
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ****************
Content-Length: 50

* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 199
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:6baf8227-a96f-4757-ac3b-a170d33a7b16
< Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=5b826c9996f848edeab28288985b46ca9013ce4aef93b8f195bc66f2f91c578c;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=ecomdashapi.azurewebsites.net
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 17:02:00 GMT
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host ecomdash.azure-api.net left intact
```

I am using Guzzle version 6.2.1

Thanks in advance for any help this is killing me.

Comment: Are you trying "both" code at the same time?

Comment: No just put them there as two examples of things I have tried. Both resulted in the same error though.

Comment: You can pass a `, ['debug' => true]` parameter for debugging purposes

Comment: I added the returned info from the debug to the question

Comment: That's strange. Can you show us the structure of `$this->auth`? But remeber to replace any password or sensitive information with `***`

Comment: This->auth = array(2) { ["ecd-subscription-key"]=> string(32) "*******************" ["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"]=> string(32) "*************************" }

Comment: This is the raw cURL command: `curl -v -XPOST -H 'ecd-subscription-key: ***' -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ***' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "Sku": "067567", "Quantity": 10, "WarehouseId":28345 }' 'https://ecomdash.azure-api.net/api/inventory/updateQuantityOnHand'` If you run it directly from the console, it works? (replace ** with proper credentials)

Comment: Still getting the body of message was missing or invalid.

Comment: This is the cURL command. If it's not working, you should contact the responsable for the API and see how to send data to them. This response seems to be custom, forcing a 400 Bad Request, it isn't a default message from a http server like apache or nginx.

Comment: Thanks for your help Felippe I have contacted them just waiting to hear back. I will post the solution once I get one.

Comment: Thanks again Felippe for your help I added the solution to the question.

Comment: No problem. You can add the solution as an answer and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is for use with the ecomdash API as it turns out when using this method all JSON strings must be enclosed in square brackets as if there was an array of products. So this actually works as expected with json_encode for an array of products but with only one product being updated you have to manually add the square brackets around the JSON. So because of this you have to use body not JSON when setting up the request. So here is the final code that worked.

```
$data[] = array("Sku" => "067567", "Quantity" => 21, "WarehouseId" => 28345);
$dataJson = json_encode($data);

//put square brackets in if only one product is being updated
if(count($data) == 1) {
  $dataJson = '['.$dataJson.']';
}

$headers = $this->auth;
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

$response = $this->client->request('POST', 'inventory/updateQuantityOnHand', array('headers' => $headers, 'body' => $dataJson));

var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
    // die()
    die();
}
```

Comment: Commenting 4 years later in case it helps anyone, this also applies to the 'EposNow' API - the JSON string must be enclosed with square brackets. If you try to add the brackets directly to the 'body' parameter it treats it as an array which Guzzle doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new Client();
$URI = 'complete_url';
$params['headers'] = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
$params = [
    'json' => [
       'kay1' => 'val1',
       'kay2' => 'val2',
     ]
    ];
$response = $client->post($URI, $params);
echo print_r(json_decode($response->getBody(),true));
die();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).